# Kubernetes: mapping between Deployments Services Pods to docker concept

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I'm learning Kubernetes. I'm trying to mapping equivalent concept from Kubernetes to Docker. For example: I have a following `docker-compose.yml`

```
db:
  container_name: db
  image: postgres:latest
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234

app:
  container_name: app
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  volumes:
    - ".:/webapp"
  env_file:
    - ./.env.docker_compose
  links:
    - db
```

This `docker-compose.yml` has two components: db and app. There are 2 ways for understanding. I don't know which one is true and which one is wrong.

- First understanding: each components are inside in each pod. This means db in one pod, and app in one pod.
- Second understanding: both db and app are all in one Pod.

Please tell me which one is true. The same question for `Deployment` and `Service`. How can I map to docker concept.

Thanks

Comment: You could try http://kompose.io/

Answer (score 1):

A pod being a group of one or more container, your docker-compose would by default mimick one pod. (so your second interpretation)

But with [docker swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/), you can make sure those two container are in their own "pod" (as a group of one container) with [constraints](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints-constraint).
With dockerfile v3, you have for instance [**placement**](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#placement) (also seen in [`docker service create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-placement-preferences-placement-pref))

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
          - engine.labels.operatingsystem == ubuntu 14.04
```